# Given that $m$ is a real number not less than $-1$

Tags: quadratics

The question is:
Given that $m$ is a real number not less than $-1$, such that the equation in $x$ is $x^2+2(m-2)x+m^2-3m+3=0$ has two distinct roots $r$ and $s$. If $r^2+s^2=6$, find the value of $m$.

Here's what I've tried:.

Using Vieta's formulas:

$rs = m^2-3m+3$
$r+s = -2m+4$

Then I set the equation as such; $(r+s)^2 - 2rs = 6$. I got $2m^2-10m+4=0$. Using the quadratic equation, I got $\frac {5+\sqrt {17}}2$ and $\frac {5-\sqrt {17}}2$. Is there anything wrong with my solution?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format.

Comment: $4m^2-16m+16-2(m^2-3m+3)=2m^2-10m+10=2(m^2-5m+5)$.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct:
$$(r+s)^2 - 2rs = 6 \iff \\
(-2(m-2))^2-2(m^2-3m+3)=6 \iff \\
(4m^2-16m+16)-2m^2+6m-6=6 \iff \\
2m^2-10m+4=0.$$
And the roots are:
$$m_{1,2}=\frac{5\pm \sqrt{17}}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The posted solution is correct up to that point, though it remains to be verified that $\,r \ne s\,$ for those values of $\,m\,$.

Alt. hint:   $\color{blue}{r+s}=-2m+4$, and each root satisfies $\,x^2= -\big(2(m-2)x+m^2-3m+3\big)\,$, so:

$$
\begin{align}
6 = r^2+s^2 &= -2(m-2)(\color{blue}{r+s})- 2(m^2-3m+3) \\
 &= 2(m-2)(2m-4)- 2(m^2-3m+3) \\
 &= 2 (m^2 - 5 m + 5)
\end{align}
$$

Then what remains to solve is $\,m^2-5m+5=3\,$ for solutions $\,\ge -1\,$ (and, again, verify that they yield *distinct* roots $\,r,s\,$).

Comment: good point about verifying, +1. Indeed, distinct roots imply $D>0 \iff (m-2)^2-m^2+3m-3>0 \iff m<1$. So, $\frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}>1$ must be rejected.